# Name of a field in the db

Tags: database

In my DB I have a table named "group". The group can be closed or open. So I need a field (boolean) for that, which is 0 or 1.
Should I name the field **closed** or **open**? Is there an official way how to name the field? I know, technically it doesn't matter, but how is this in general?

Thanks Ivo

Comment: I usually choose it in a way that reduces the number of negations I need. `where not is_closed` is harder to read than `where is_open`. If however you mainly query for closed groups then apparently `where is_closed` would be the better choice. Another option would be a `varchar` column containing `open` and `closed` (secured with a check constraint). That will make the table bigger but queries easier to read: e.g. `where state = 'open'`. But this is really very much a personal preference. Which DBMS are you using? A _real_ `boolean` would be a better choice than a column containing 0/1.

Comment: Thank you! I will call the field "open". The type of the field will be tinyint(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion I'd have this field called **Open**. In computing terms 0 is false and 1 is true. Reflecting this onto your Open and Closed scenario, it makes more sense to have Open as true and Closed as false. So when the field says 1 it is open. Hope this helps your approach.